# Updated to Chrome 94.0.4606.61 and now mouse wheel sometimes scrolls in increments of only two pixels

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I think the question title sums it up: scrolling is just really slow on some web pages or parts of pages now, because Chrome thinks the correct scroll amount for a mouse wheel "tick" is just a couple of pixels or so. I tried looking at this blog post:

[Stable Channel Update for Desktop](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/09/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_24.html)

It points to this [change log](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/94.0.4606.54..94.0.4606.61?pretty=fuller&n=10000)

Which doesn't mention anything about scrolling or mouse wheels.  However, it's possible that I "skipped" a version or two; I don't know how to find out what my previous Chrome version was.  Any advice?

Comment: Not here (Chrome 94 newest).  Have you tried updating Mouse driver, Video, Chipset (if one)?

Comment: I assume you have either tried restarting the browser and/or restarting the machine?  This sounds more of a hardware issue that is typically resolved by rebooting.

Comment: (I am not on 94 newest.)  I'm on a corporate laptop; I can't upgrade my mouse drivers and stuff.  I'm pretty convinced it's not a hardware issue because it only happens on some web pages, but on those particular pages it is consistent.  Further, other programs are fine; only chrome is giving me trouble.

Comment: Ask your IT people to update your machine because you are having problems.

Comment: That's a good idea actually; I will try that.

Comment: Okay it was actually a pretty bad idea because the IT department took forever to get back to me.  By the time they did, I got another browser update and now it works fine.